# Problem when capturing json values and assigning those values to python list

Tags: python, json

I have json code from which I need to get `requestId` and `emailTypeDesc` that are inside `emailList`. This action has to be perform for each item on `emailRequest` list, see below:

json:

```
{
'readOnly': False,
'senderDetails': {'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Doe', 'emailAddress': 'johndoe@gmail.com', 'emailAddressId': 123456, 'personalId': 123, 'companyName': 'ACME‘},
'clientDetails': {'firstName': 'Jane', 'lastName': 'Doe', 'emailAddress': 'janedoe@gmail.com', 'emailAddressId': 654321, 'personalId': 456, 'companyName': 'Lorem Ipsum‘}},
'notesSection': {},
'emailList': [{'requestId': 12345667, 'emailId': 9876543211, 'emailType': 3, 'emailTypeDesc': 'Email-In', 'emailTitle': 'SampleTitle 1', 'createdDate': '15-May-2020 11:15:52', 'fromMailList': [{'firstName': 'Jane', 'lastName': 'Doe', 'emailAddress': 'janedoe@gmail.com',}]},
              {'requestId': 12345667, 'emailId': 14567775, 'emailType': 3, 'emailTypeDesc': 'Email-Out', 'emailTitle': 'SampleTitle 2', 'createdDate': '16-May-2020 16:15:52', 'fromMailList': [{'firstName': 'Jane', 'lastName': 'Doe', 'emailAddress': 'janedoe@gmail.com',}]},
              {'requestId': 12345667, 'emailId': 12345, 'emailType': 3, 'emailTypeDesc': 'Email-In', 'emailTitle': 'SampleTitle 3', 'createdDate': '17-May-2020 20:15:52', 'fromMailList': [{'firstName': 'Jane', 'lastName': 'Doe', 'emailAddress': 'janedoe@gmail.com',}]   
}
```

Python code:

```
emailRequest=['12345667']
final_list = []

def get_emailRequest_details(emailRequest, tokenId, userId):
headers = {     'accept': 'application/json', 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                'access-token': tokenId,
                'userID': userId}
endpoint = 'emailRequest/' + x + '/details'
r = requests.get(url = HOSTNAME + endpoint, headers = headers, verify=False)
data = json.loads(r.text)
myDesc = [(data['emailList'][0]['emailTypeDesc'])]
for each_requ in myDesc:
    final_list.append(each_requ)
return final_list

for x in emailRequest:
    get_emailRequest_details(x, tokenId, userId)
```

However, when running the above code I can't get all values for `emailTypeDesc` (expected 3 list items, but code returns only latest). Also, not sure how I could get both attributes at the same time (`requestId`, `emailTypeDesc`) and add `requestId` on the front of my final_list.

Current output for final_list:

```
['Email-In']
```

Desired output for final_list:

```
[12345667, 'Email-In', 'Email-Out', 'Email-In']
```

Please note that this code will be looping through unknown number of email requests on this list: `emailRequest`, it can be one request at the time like in this example or many depending on the time this code will run.

So for multiple emailRequest my final_list output would look like:

```
[12345667, 'Email-In', 'Email-Out', 'Email-In', 987654, 'Email-In', 'Email-Out', 567843, 'Email-In', 'Email-Out', 'Email-In', 'Email-Out', 'Email-In', 'Email-In']
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong here:

```
myDesc = [(data['emailList'][0]['emailTypeDesc'])]
for each_requ in myDesc:
    final_list.append(each_requ)
return final_list
```

Could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `myDesc = [(data['emailList'][0]['emailTypeDesc'])]`

You're taking the 'emailTypeDesc' of the first 'emailList' and iterating over it.

What i think you need is `myDesc = [mails['emailTypeDesc'] for mails in data['emailList']]` and then iterate over it.

Comment: thanks a lot Kay! this solved my issue. However, would you know how could I add `requestId` from my `emailList` in front of the results in `final_list`? Now I managed to get `final_list`=['Email-In', 'Email-Out', 'Email-In']. I would need requestId to show in front of this with no repetition, so `final_list`= [12345667, 'Email-In', 'Email-Out', 'Email-In'].

Comment: Nevermind, I added something like this and worked:     myId = [(data['emailList'][0]['requestId'])]
    for each_req in myId:
        final_list.append(each_req)